# Can't get audio to play from paths stored in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, audio

I'm building a digital dictionary with audio files for each word saved in an "audio" folder on the disk and paths to those audio files stored in a data column in my MySQL table. I'm trying to query the path into the HTML audio tag like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT adl, ipa, audio FROM lexicon";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "ADL: " . $row["adl"]. " IPA: " . $row["ipa"]. " Audio: <audio controls><source src=\"". $row["audio"]."\" type=\"audio/wav\"></audio><br>";
}
} else {
 echo "0 results";
}
```

If you go to the page, the audio player seems to be reading the 1 second audio file: https://memoriaelinguagrumentina.org/audio/englishDictionary.php
But the audio won't play. Why is that?

This webpage is stored in the same "audio" folder as the audio files. And the path in my data column is "/audio/a1.wav". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<div class="nav>` element is above your `<audio>` element.

You can see this easily by adding `background: black` to `.nav` in your styles - you will see that the audio controls disappear.

You can fix this in several ways, including adding `margin-top` to push your content below your header, or adding `z-index` to your `<audio>` element to raise it above the header elements. Then you will be able to click the Play button and it will work. (I tested this in the Chrome DevTools.)

However, it looks like your header has other design issues (make your window smaller for one example of how it breaks), so you probably want to make other changes to the header design too.

Comment: Wow, I never even considered that. Yes, I haven't even started with the responsive design yet, and there are a ton of problems to fix. I've been preoccupied with trying to get the audio to work. But thank you! I think you found the issue.

Comment: As a new contributor, if the answer above is correct, please mark it as such and upvote.